# call to API works async, but I need it run sync

Tags: c#, api, synchronization

I've been trying for a day to make this work synchronously, not async.

Here is the code that works:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                 
HttpClient clientPageFirst = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage responsePageFirst = await clientPageFirst.GetAsync(fullURL);
HttpContent contentPageFirst = responsePageFirst.Content;

string resultPageFirst = await contentPageFirst.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(resultPageFirst);
```

It's for a C# console app, and there is another call there to another platform's API which works synchronously, but it uses tokens in the header to validate, not a network credential like this one (calling a local on premise CRM URL).

Can someone please help me change the

```
HttpResponseMessage responsePageFirst = await clientPageFirst.GetAsync(fullURL);
```

line so it is synchronous?

T.I.A.

Comment: could you please explain what exactly the _problem_ is with running async?

Comment: well, if you need to know, it's because 1. it's a console app, 2. i need to loop though pages,and save each page and 3. there is another call to a different API in the same app which works fine in sync. and finally, because it's easier doing it all in a console app when it's in sync

Comment: may be he doesn't want to change the method signature to async/Task etc?

Comment: Have you considered changing your `Main` method to be `async`? Is that an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: @RodneyEllis sorry, but i just don't see how any of those points contradicts with using async methods.

Comment: "to another platform's API which works synchronously", the `await` usage ensure execution flow await the results at that line.. so if the call your making doesn't support async/task await then you would just substitute that line with the synchronous call.

Comment: after looking at the accepted answer and commenting to effect, you should update your snippet to include the entire method signature for this scope, and reflect on your intention to have that method not be `async`.  *though I still think the problem with this question is that your approach is generally unrecommended, and that you should consider an approach to call this other platform's API asynchronously.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
`HttpResponseMessage responsePageFirst = clientPageFirst.GetAsync("fullURL").Result;`

Comment: thanks, that kinda works, but how do i read the result into resultPageFirst ? ie. the  ReadAsStringAsync() function now needs to change. can you add that too please?

Comment: you can do `string resultPageFirst = contentPageFirst.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` you can call (dot).Result to make the calls sync

Comment: how is this different then the current implementation that does `await`?  ...or was it based on the presumption that the scope of this method was removing `async`?

Comment: in the snippet of code that the OP provided., What additional benefit does using the aync/await provide?

Comment: Stephen C's Blog: [Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)